# Android draw shadow below view: dispatchDraw called often - any cache missed

Tags: android, caching, shadow

I'm trying to drop a smooth shadow under a view element. Here's is what I've done so far:

Subclass FrameLayout (my ShadowViewport), which overrides dispatchDraw(...) and does:

- Call dispatchDraw of superclass and save output as bitmap
- Extract alpa from this bitmap
- Blur
- Draw blurred extracted alpha with some offset
- Draw original view bitmap

  ```
  @Override
  protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      Log.d("ShadowViewport", "dispatchDraw");

      final Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
      final Canvas sCanvas = new Canvas(output);

      // Draw internal view in canvas
      super.dispatchDraw(sCanvas);
      final Bitmap original = output.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);

      Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
      paint.setColor(0x55000000);
      paint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(SHADOW_SIZE, Blur.NORMAL));

      canvas.drawBitmap(output.extractAlpha(), 0, SHADOW_SIZE, paint);
      canvas.drawBitmap(original, 0, 0, null);
  }
  ```

**Result**

[Find image here](http://img254.imageshack.us/img254/4647/shadowa.png).
As you can see, the left box has a nice generated shadow, even for rounded corners ;)

**The question**

The on dispatchDraw function is called very often, for example while scrolling. Is there any way for caching?

Comment: did you have any luck with it?

Comment: Not yet. For now I'm using a simple 9-patch drawable, which fits for very simple shapes. The "real" shadow could cover even a complex view...

Comment: Please paste your source code here..

Comment: @Algo: The code for the 9-patch drawable? It's just a drawable set as background for (in example) a RelativeLayout: `android:background="@drawable/item_single_background"`.
Find the image [here](http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/7742/itemsinglebackground9.png).

Answer (score 0):

Enabling the android:hardwareAccelerated="true" attribute in the AndroidManifest will enable automatic caching of the image. Ithe  dispatchDraw method is not called for example, during scrolling.

I also think it is possible to use the [setDrawingCacheEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setDrawingCacheEnabled%28boolean%29) on your Layout Class. To make that work you should call getDrawingCache first, and the the returned bitmap if it is not null. This seems a bit like a "poor man's" optimization, but is probably a good idea to get performance out of older phones.